# How do I enter ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι in TeX?

Tags: fonts, formatting, typography, languages

How do I typeset [this statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398794/greek-life-calquoderatdemonstrandum?noredirect=1#comment853370_398794)

[image]

if I'm using

`\usepackage[default]{frcursive}`

and

`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

in my TEX file?

Comment: I tried rendering this while using `frcursive` but I got something opposite the expected result.

Comment: "this statment" := ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι

Comment: @HenriMenke: Thank you for up voting the edited title. :-)

Comment: @ClickMe -- Not sure if it's just me, but I don't get a `π` in the title..?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `pdfTeX` (i.e., use `latex` or `pdflatex` to compile) and a transliteration for 'ancient' Greek:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\parindent0pt
\useackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% 
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,english]{babel}

% switch to language environments  
\newcommand{\latin}[1]{%
          \foreignlanguage{latin}{#1}}
\newcommand{\grk}[1]{%
          \foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}}

\begin{document} 

English: That which had to be demonstrated. 

Latin: \latin{Quod erat demonstrandum.}

% transliteration of ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι     
Greek: \grk{<'oper >edei de~ixai.}

\end{document}
```

Or, using the `XeTeX` engine (command: `xelatex`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\parindent0pt

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}% <-- pick a font with Greek characters
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek}

\begin{document}

English: That which had to be demonstrated.

Latin: \textlatin{Quod erat demonstrandum.}

Greek: \textgreek{ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, I found it. This is what comes up when the installation prompt shows up: fonts\tfm\public\cbgreek\grmn1095.tfm I try to install it, but afterwards it just stalls. Perhaps I'm not waiting long enough?

Comment: I don't think so. At least not immediately. Maybe later it will fall into place.

Comment: v2.3 is what is listed in the PDF contained in my MiKTeK folder.

Comment: "going to download 66499167 bytes" says MiKTeX.

Comment: `cbgreek.tar.lzma` is the file it's downloading. According to [CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/greek/cbfonts) this is really a large file. I have already used `xparse` so the `l3` stuff should be already here.

Comment: @Trancot, Jon: Could you please clean up all outdated comments you don't need any longer. This comment threads is getting a little too long. Note that you can use a custom chat room if you need to have a longer conversation.

Comment: What about on a Mac?

Comment: @Trancot -- I haven't used a Mac since the early '90s.  There is TeX Live and (I think) MacTeX.  If you are having serious problems with these files, you should open a new questions about: (1) MikTeX not having `grmn1095.tfm`; and/or (2) a `fontspec`/`xparse` clash.  Provide a minimal example (as in this answer), how you are compiling the file, and a description of the errors you get.